# Code snippet button bind twice

Tags: bug

Some time code snippet button bind  twice.After refresh the page problem is solved. [image]

Answer (score -3):

You must be repeating this code snippet in your code kindly check your code in page source and you will have a clear idea

Comment: No, that is an actual bug. Sometimes I even see 3 rows